# How to remove string with specific value from a string using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

Suppose my string is like:

```
var str = "USA;UK;AUS;NZ"
```

Now from some a source I am getting one value like:

```
country.data = "AUS"
```

Now in this case I want to remove "AUS" from my string.

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve this.

Here is what I have tried:

```
var someStr= str.substring(0, str.indexOf(country.data))
```

In this case I got the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *split* and *filter*:

```js
var str = "USA;UK;AUS;NZ"
var toBeRemoved = "AUS";
var res = str.split(';').filter(s => s !== toBeRemoved).join(';');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: In this case I left with two `;;`

Comment: I've updated, take a look

Comment: Thanks I am checking

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
var result = str.replace(country.data + ';','');
```

Thanks to comments, this should work more efficently :

```
var tmp = str.replace(country.data ,''); 
var result = tmp.replace(';;' ,';');
```

Comment: This results in `'USA;UK;;NZ'`, leaving an orphaned delimiter. Yes, `AUS` is gone, but it's doubtful this is the desired output.

Comment: I edited. try now.

Comment: you've still the case of the final value. Say you wanted to remove `NZ`... this would fail.

Comment: var result = str.replace(country.data ,''); var result2 = result .replace(';;' ,';'); This hould work. @ᴄʜaᴢsᴏʟᴏ

Answer (score 2):

```js
var str = "USA;UK;AUS;NZ"
console.log(str + " <- INPUT");
str = str.split(';');

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] == 'AUS') {
    str.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
console.log(str.join(';') + " <- OUTPUT");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good old split/join method:

```js
var str = "USA;UK;AUS;NZ;AUS";
var str2 = "AUS";
var str3 = str2 + ";";
console.log(str.split(str3).join("").split(str2).join(""));
```

Comment: In this case I left with two `;;`

Comment: @David, yes, but it's easy to solve, just add `+ ";"` to your second string. I have updated the answer.

Comment: this fails if you want to remove the final value

Comment: @ᴄʜaᴢsᴏʟᴏ, updated

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with a regex containing the searched country, this is how should be the regex `/(AUS;?)/`.

This is how should be your code:

```js
var str = "USA;UK;AUS;NZ";
var country = "AUS";
var reg = new RegExp("("+country+";?)");
str = str.replace(reg, '');
console.log(str);
```

This will remove the `;` after your country if it exists.